# How to insert a rating image in the WordPress comment section?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need to insert a verification image in the WordPress comment box. If rating is 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, then not-verified images should be shown and if the rating is 5/5 verified image should be shown. I tried many versions but was able to show only one image at time in all the comment box if the rating is grater than or less than 5.

My code 1:

```
var code = $("<strong>5 / 5</strong>");
code.each(function() {
    $('p.comment-rating').prepend('<p class="prepen_img"><img src="verified.png" /></p>');
});
```

My code 2:

```
if ($("p.comment-rating:contains('2 / 5')").length !== 0) {
    $('p.comment-rating').prepend('<p class="prepen_img"><img src="not-verified.png" /></p>');
}
else {
    $('p.comment-rating').prepend('<p class="prepen_img"><img src="verified.png" /></p>');
}
```

My code 3:

```
$('p.comment-rating').each(function() {
    if ($("p.comment-rating:contains('5 / 5')").length !== 0) {
        $('p.comment-rating').prepend('<p class="prepen_img"><img src="not-verified.png" /></p>');
    }
    else {
        $('p.comment-rating').prepend('<p class="prepen_img"><img src="verified.png" /></p>');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<p class="comment-rating">
    <img src="2star.gif">
    <br>
    Rating: <strong>2 / 5</strong>
</p>
```

The above code only shows one images, `else` condition is not working.

Comment: Can you please help anybody?

Comment: You have a rating system in wordpress and you wanna show `not-verified` or `verified` image next to it, depending on the rating? Does it output html, as you've shown in your question `Rating: <strong>2 / 5</strong>`?

Comment: @ Joonas , Absolutely  Right. That 2/5 is the out put of the rating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this could work:

<kbd>[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/f52vp0zj/)</kbd>

Html:

```
<p class="comment-rating">
    Rating: <strong>2 / 5</strong>
</p>

<p class="comment-rating">
    Rating: <strong>5 / 5</strong>
</p>

<p class="comment-rating">
    Rating: <strong>1 / 5</strong>
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $('.comment-rating').each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            // Finds the first number inside '.comment-rating strong' before the forward slash and converts it to a number.
            rating = parseInt( $this.find('strong').text().split('/')[0] ); 

        var verify = rating === 5 ? 'Verified' : 'Not-verified';

        $this.append('<span>'+ verify +'</span>');

    });

});
```

---

I figured the text example would be more clear, since I don't have such images, but here's that same thing with images, where I changed line 9 and line 11 slightly:

<kbd>[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/f52vp0zj/1/)</kbd>

Same html.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $('.comment-rating').each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            // Finds the first number inside '.comment-rating strong' before the forward slash and converts it to a number.
            rating = parseInt( $this.find('strong').text().split('/')[0] ); 

        var verify = rating === 5 ? 'http://placekitten.com/g/20/30' : 'http://placekitten.com/20/30';

        $this.append('<img src="'+ verify +'" />');

    });

});
```

Comment: Wow.. You are amazing! Incredible!. you did a magic!. Its working well. Many many Thanks Dearest Jonnas..Thanks again.. Could you please explain why did my code not working?

Comment: @KevinJohn Yea, I don't really know why I discarded your code from the get go. Anyways, the issue stems from the fact that [you were not using `$(this)` inside your `.each()` function](http://jsfiddle.net/f52vp0zj/4/). For the life of me I can't seem to be able to explain this in simple terms, so I'll just urge you to play around with `console.log();` and use for example chrome developer tools console to see what values it gives. E.g. `console.log( $(this) );` and `console.log( $('.comment-rating') );`